# Continuous deployment to Google Play fails when using android sdk 24

Tags: xamarin.android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I am currently developing an Android application using Xamarin Forms (v2.3.3.180) and Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine.

I have a problem deploying APKs from TFS built with Android 7.0 (SDK 24) to Google Play.

Previously my app was built with, and targeted Android 6.0 (SDK 23), but I recently updated it to compile and target version 7.0, while maintaining the minimum supported version of 4.4.2 (SDK 19).

This presents no problem while developing and building the app, but when deploying it to Google Play it will not do the update. I have also tested to deploy it manually with the same result. The message states that the app previously targeted SDK 23 and cannot be downgraded to **SDK 0**!!!

This image is not mine as I forgot to take a screenshot of the message, but the text is exactly the same **except for the version numbers**:
[Error message when deploying the APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emmdA.png)

Mine said “… *This occurs in the change from version xxx (target SDK 23) to version xxx+1 (target **SDK 0**)*

After reverting to SDK 23 in my manifest.xml everything builds and deploys fine.

I have been able to find other examples of this error message, but all of them are valid errors in which Google Play should give this message. Mine is not, as it seems to think I am using SDK 0.

Has anyone come across this before? Is this a problem with Android 7.0, Xamarin build support, my TFS build machine, Google Play APK checks or something else?

(The SDKs are installed on the build machine!)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean developing and building the app could be successful through TFS except deploy to google play not do the update? If so seems not related to TFSbuild.

Comment: Yes and no. The build is ok on both my devlopment machine and using TFS, but the deploy fails from TFS, but NOT from my machine. My build with SDK 24 does not fail to deploy, but TFS build with SDK 24 does. Somehow the build from TFS sets the targeted framework to 0 (zero).